# I try to make a guess game and let user decide under what max number to guess

Tags: java, eclipse

In oder to check the value entered by the user AND to see what random number has been calculated, I want to let those numbers projected in the console (eclipse). But what sketches my astonishment?? the last two system.out.println's (right above invoermax.close())) do NOT appear in the console screen after I entered the number???? It's like java doesn't even read or notice these code lines, How come???

Here my code:

```
package Package1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;


public class test6KOPIE1 {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Invoermax = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Under which number you want to guess");

        int Invoer = Invoermax.nextInt();


        int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,Invoermax.nextInt());



        System.out.println("So a guess under max: " + Invoer);

        System.out.println("The random number has become " + Hoogte);

        Invoermax.close();

    }   

}
```

Comment: Its scanner, whenever you call other than nextLine() scanner will leave an empty space behind, to over come it call nextLine() on scanner object after each nextInt() call

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply, but can you be more precise, I don't really see what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

every time you call `Scanner.nextInt()` it will wait for input from you.

The problem is that you are calling it twice, replace:

```
    int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,Invoermax.nextInt());
```

With the variable you already got:

```
    int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,Invoer);
```

And BTW, usually in java you start field/variable name with lower case letter, so should be `hoogte`, `inoverMax`, `inover` etc.

Comment: The next thing is, I need that random value to export to an other class and methode. But I understood you can't export value's created in a public static void -methode to an other methode? is that true? or is there an escape?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
// code
Scanner Invoermax = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Under which number you want to guess"); 
int Invoer = Invoermax.nextInt();
Invoermax.nextLine(); // reading empty space left
int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,Invoermax.nextInt()); 
// code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two *scanner.nextInt()* calls, so there are two input readings, two input waitings.

```
    int Invoer = Invoermax.nextInt();   // the first input reading
    int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,
                  Invoermax.nextInt());  // the second input reading
```

When you enter two int values in a console (any of the kind) you'll see your ending print rows.

If your design was to have a single input, then use cashed value for the second usage

```
    int Invoer = Invoermax.nextInt();   // the first input reading
    int Hoogte = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,
                  Invoer );             // use cashed value
```